# Is a corrupted zip more recoverable if it was created using the "store" method?

Tags: dvd, zip

I have large zip files (2Gb+) that contain something along the lines of 1500 compressed zip files, but the large files are themselves not compressed ("store" used) - is that method more suitable to try and recover the large zip files if they're corrupted or partially non-readable (say off of a DVD+R)?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have a clue though :)

Answer (score 0):

AFIK compressing is used eg. by PGP also to make guessing harder, so I would risk to put the thesis that non compressed data is easier to recover. Also I feel like remembering from my information theory course that compressed data is typically nearer to random than uncompressed data.